# Python - I'm trying to send an email to myself

Tags: python, email

So I'm using the module Mail1: https://pypi.org/project/mail1/ to send an email to myself using my Btinternet account as the sender. Here is the code:

```
import mail1

mail1.send(subject='Test',
           text='This is a test!',
           recipients='RECIPIENTS EMAIL',
           sender='MY EMAIL',
           password='MY PASSWORD',
           smtp_host='mail.btinternet.com')
```

but I get this error:

```
"C:\Users\rayne\PycharmProjects\python project\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/rayne/PycharmProjects/python project/mail test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rayne/PycharmProjects/python project/mail test.py", line 8, in <module>
    smtp_host='mail.btinternet.com')
  File "C:\Users\rayne\PycharmProjects\python project\venv\lib\site-packages\mail1\mail1.py", line 95, in send
    smtp.sendmail(sender, recipients+cc+bcc, message.as_string())
  File "C:\Users\rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 867, in sendmail
    raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'authentication required - Your email could not be sent. To fix this you must make a simple change to your email client (known as SMTP authentication). For advice visit http://www.bt.com/smtp', 'MY EMAIL')
```

How do I authenticate it so it can send? Thanks!

Ok, so I just tried a different method, here is the code:

```
import mail1
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL


with SMTP_SSL('imap.mail.me.com', 993) as smtp:
    smtp.login('MY ICLOUD ACCOUNT', 'APP-SPECIFIC PASSWORD')
```

But I now have a new error:

```
"C:\Users\rayne\PycharmProjects\python project\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/rayne/PycharmProjects/python project/mail test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rayne/PycharmProjects/python project/mail test.py", line 12, in <module>
    with SMTP_SSL('imap.mail.me.com', 993) as smtp:
  File "C:\Users\rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 1031, in __init__
    source_address)
  File "C:\Users\rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 254, in __init__
    raise SMTPConnectError(code, msg)
smtplib.SMTPConnectError: (-1, b'[CAPABILITY XAPPLEPUSHSERVICE IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR AUTH=ATOKEN AUTH=PLAIN] (2108B29-d5d83408a736) st43p00im-tygg10060801.me.com')
```

Comment: You missed the `username`.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, do you mean when I call mail1.send()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do SMTP authentication you need to supply the username argument in `mail1.send`:

```py
import mail1

mail1.send(subject='Test',
           text='This is a test!',
           recipients='RECIPIENTS EMAIL',
           sender='MY EMAIL',
           username='MY USERNAME',
           password='MY PASSWORD',
           smtp_host='mail.btinternet.com')
```

The full list of args you can supply is readily found on the PyPI page.

Comment: Thanks! Ok so I just added my username but i have a new error:

Comment: I believe username usually refers to the email you login with. You might be able to find more info in the SMTP settings of your email provider

Comment: Ok i found out my username (it is just my email) but i have a new error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rayne/PycharmProjects/python project/mail test.py", line 9, in <module>
    smtp_host='mail.btinternet.com')
  File "C:\Users\rayne\PycharmProjects\python project\venv\lib\site-packages\mail1\mail1.py", line 92, in send
    smtp.starttls()
  File "C:\Users\rayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 752, in starttls
    "STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: That's probably something to do with the specific values you passed to the arguments. Check out https://www.bt.com/help/email/manage-email-account/manual-settings/what-are-the-settings-for-outgoing-and-incoming-bt-email-servers since you are using BT

Comment: Ok thanks i chanfes a few things and it worked!